# VBA Autofilter by whether a cell contains a number formatted as a string

Tags: vba, excel

So I am writing a macro that sorts through a sheet by columns and clears cells containing certain kinds of data, specifically if they are numeric. My existing code  does something like this to catch all number fields and clear them:

```
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=(i + 1), Criteria1:=">0"
    Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(70000, i + 1)).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData


    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=(i + 1), Criteria1:="=0"
    Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(70000, i + 1)).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

which works fine for cells which contain numbers in number format. Some of the cells contain numbers formatted as strings, ie what

```
="80"
```

would produce when typed into excel. I need to create a criteria for this autofilter that recognizes if a cell contains a number formatted as a string, but I dont know how, since the Criteria:=">0" and Criteria:="=0" are ignored by strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way :) I have commented the code but if you still have any questions, feel free to post back.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    With Sheet1           
        '~~> Change format of the column to number
        '~~> This is an example for Col A
        '~~> Change as applicable
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "0"

        '~~> Convert number stored as text to number
        .Columns(1).Formula = .Columns(1).Value

        '~~> Use Special Cells to select all cells containing numbers
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        rng.ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0           
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify something so complicated as the criterion of AutoFilter.

However, here is a workaround:

1. Create a UDF like this:

   ```
   Function IsTextNumeric(r As Range) As Boolean
       If Application.IsText(r) And IsNumeric(r) Then
           IsTextNumeric = True
       Else
           IsTextNumeric = False
       End If
   End Function
   ```
2. Programmatically create a Conditional Formatting for that range of cells. Conditional formatting allows you to specify a formula and use the true/false value of that expression to decide whether to apply formatting to the cell. The formula should just refer to the UDF. The Conditional Formatting to apply is cell coloring.
3. AutoFilter allows you to use cell coloring as a criterion.